# Some special characters are allowed only if they are preceded by an escape character

Tags: regex, ocaml, lex, ocamllex

I want to construct a [regular expression (in the style of lex, with a more OCaml-like syntax)](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lexyacc.html#regexp) for a class of strings, where **4 characters `[`, `]`, `#`, `'` are allowed only if they are preceded by an escape character `'`**.

Here are some valid examples:

- `'#Data`, `abc'#Headers`, `abc'#Totals'[efg`, `123'#Totals']efg`, `abc`, `123`

Here are some non-valid examples:

- `#Data`, `abc#Headers`, `abc#Totals[efg`,`123#Totals]efg`, `'#Totals[efg`

Hope the definition is clear. First, does anyone know how to construct such a regular expression? Second, does anyone know how to construct such a [regular expression (in the style of lex, with a more OCaml-like syntax)](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lexyacc.html#regexp) that can be accepted by ocamllex?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps a regex that looks for an optional escape char followed by anything might work `^[^\[\]#']*('.*)?$`

Comment: @IronMan Thank you for your comment, I tested your proposition in https://www.regextester.com/, it seems that it considers `'#Totals[efg` valid. However, `'#Totals[efg` is not valid for me because `[` is not preceded by `'`.

Comment: Perhaps one or more non-special chars followed by an optional escape sequence `^([^\[\]#']*('[\[\]#'])*)*$`

Comment: The lex regex is `([^][#']|'[][#'])*`. (Or change `*` to `+` if you don't allow empty strings.) But I gather that the "more OCaml-lilke syntax" requires escaping some of those characters, at least the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say the accepted strings look like other than with a few examples. Just for concreteness, let's say that lower-case letters and digits are allowed, and the 4 special characters are allowed only if preceded by `'`.

This, then, is described by the Kleene closure of a set of 36 one-character strings and 4 two-character strings.

Which looks like this:

```
 (['a' - 'z' '0' - '9'] | '\'' ['\'' '#' '[' ']'])*
```